# MobileElement not exist in java-client 8.0.0

Tags: java, android-studio, appium

I can't find a way to import MobileElement for code I copy after following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1tQ1pjEFWw&t=1915s&ab_channel=edureka%21 in Appium for testing Android.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MobileElement el3 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.example.calculator:id/button2");
        el3.click();
        MobileElement el4 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.example.calculator:id/button5");
        el4.click();
        MobileElement el5 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.example.calculator:id/buttonPlus");
        el5.click();
        MobileElement el6 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.example.calculator:id/button3");
        el6.click();
        MobileElement el7 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.example.calculator:id/button9");
        el7.click();

    }
}
```

But the recorded code has MobileElement, so I do the same by downloading libraries from this site: http://appium.io/downloads.html.

[This is my library which was downloaded from appium.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXauz.png)

But later, it showed me that it doesn't have MobileElement library, so I can't import it.

[Cannot resolve symbol 'MobileElement'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biNoA.png)

Is it because the code is old or does the library have an update that I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the same thing. My solution is to switch to released java-client, not the  beta version.

```
implementation files('libs\\java-client-7.6.0.jar')

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.6.0
```

Good luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Appium java-client v8 uses Selenium4 and introduces a lot of breaking changes.

You can look here
https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md#mobileelement.

It's recommended to use WebElement interface type instead of MobileElement.

Appium java-client v8 seems to be W3C compliant. So moving to a new API is a step into the future. At least after final 8.0.0 release (it's beta right now).